# Right way to make my own collection in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to do my own collection class in java.

I need to find data by a key and also be able to iterate on it and get a element by his index, so i decide to make an encapsulation of the hashtable and the arraylist.

This is my code:

```
public class GeoCollection <T extends Geographic> implements Iterable<T>, Iterator<T>{

private Hashtable<String,T> data_table;
private ArrayList<T> data;
private int cursor = 0;

public GeoCollection(){
    data = new ArrayList<>();
    data_table = new Hashtable<>();
}

public void add(String key,T data){
    this.data.add(data);
    data_table.put(key,data);
}

public T get(int index){
    if(index >= data.size())
        throw  new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    return data.get(index);
}

public T get(String v){
    return data_table.get(v);
}

public T next() {
    if( cursor == data.size())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    cursor++;
    return data.get(cursor-1);
}

public T first(){
    cursor = 0;
    return data.get(cursor);
}
public boolean hasNext(){
    return cursor < data.size();
}

public boolean remove(Person p) {
    return data.remove(p);
}

//se implemeta el iterator
@Override
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    cursor = 0;
    return this;
}
```

}

There's any need to implement list interface or something like that? Because i don't know if encapsulating the hashtable and the arraylist and implementing the basic operations in enough to call "Collection" this class.

I will be very thankful for any advice or correction of this code.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not implement the `Collection` interface?

Comment: This is more likely on-topic at [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You cannot implement `List` (at least not the parts about adding), because List entries don't have keys. You probably want to implement `Map`.

Comment: Why not just use one of the `Map`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the best way to do this is **implementing Collection**

```
implements java.util.Collection<E>
```

that way you have to implement every method in the collection interface bt 
making your class **extending AbstractCollection** `extends AbstractCollection` is much more easy since it does 
all the  nessessary  things for us and only thing you have to worry about is 
`iterator()` and `size()`